# How to get an angle between 3 points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to get the angle between the direction ball **A** is moving and Ball **B** on the x and z axis. Also i am using Unity Netcode (idk if it makes a difference or not)

[image]

so far i have tried to get i with 3 points
**A***-ball A position*,
**B***-ball B position*,
**C***-ball A position on last frame*.
i've tried

```
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x) - Mathf.Atan2(A.y - C.y, A.x - C.x);
```

and it gave me an angle but it was nowhere close to what it should have been. Then i copied some Acos code off of here but that didn't work ither.

```
float dot = C.x * B.x + C.y * B.y;
float angle = Mathf.Acos(dot);
```

then i tried Vector3.Angle and it sometimes worked but sometimes it didn't.

```
float angle = Vector3.Angle(B, C);
```

plz help, i'm new to this.

Comment: If you're using Unity, I'd recommend tagging it since there may be Unity-specific libraries to help you.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the angle by 180/π? In both computer science and mathematics we tend to use arc radians instead of arc degrees.

Comment: @Aron i've used the `Mathf.Rad2Deg();` which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A`, `B` and `C` are not vectors, they are points. If you want to compute the angle between two vectors, you should use `B - A` and `A - C`.

```
float angle = Vector3.Angle(B - A, A - C);
```

Comment: Also, I just noticed that OP isn't measuring the angles between the three points. He is trying to measure the compliment (180 - angle).

Comment: @Aron No he is not ...